# A question about triangle inequality in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

When does equality hold in the triangle inequality
$$|z_1+z_2+\dots+z_n|\leq|z_1|+|z_2|+\dots+|z_n|$$
Interpret your result geometrically

how to solve this problem i am really don't have please help me with this

for n=2
$|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1^2+2Re(z_1\overline{z_2)}+|z_2|^2\\
\leq |z_1|^2+2z_1\overline{z_2}+|z_2|^2$

hence $|z_1+z_2|\leq|z_1|+|z_2|$

Comment: Can you answer the $n=2$ version?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown..sure i try to edit

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown.. i did

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown..When does equality hold in the triangle inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:)**

For $n=2$ use ${\bf Re\,}(z_1\overline{z_2})\leqslant|z_1||z_2|$ and by induction prove the general case!

For geometrically result, consider $z_i$ as a vector and see parallelogram rule to obtain geometrically consideration.

[image]

here $z=z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5$.

Comment: @MyGlasses..my question is when does inquality hold

Comment: When ${\bf Re\,}(z_1\overline{z_2})=|z_1||z_2|$.

Comment: @suresh In general case, all $z_i$'s must be parallel. Case $n=2$ shows it as well.

Comment: @myglasses.....thank you..can you show geomerically

Comment: You want an image?

Comment: @myglasses....yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65576/discussion-between-suresh-and-myglasses).

Comment: ..i want image can you provide me

Comment: I couldn't find suitable image in web. Wait to draw!

Comment: @MyGlasses...sure